# How can I add a async function in flutter flow?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to add a async function inside flutter flow, I tried to make a custom widget with async function inside it but that not works, the text is showing "working ->". I have also tried flutter builder but that too doesn't works and have same result. Here what I have tried in custom widget->

```
class _GetLocationNameFromLatLng2State
    extends State<GetLocationNameFromLatLng2> {
  var currentLocationName = "-> ";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getLocationNameFromLatLng(widget.lat, widget.lng);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Text(
      "working $currentLocationName",
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24),
    ));
  }

  Future<String> getLocationNameFromLatLng(double? lat, double? lang) async {
    if (lat == null || lang == null) {
      print("lat == null || lang == null");
      return "";
    }

    List<Placemark> placemarks2 =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, lang);
    Placemark place2 = placemarks2[0];

    print("location found ${place2.locality}");

    if (place2.locality == null) {
      return "Couldn't found locality name";
    } else {
      print("placemarks found!!!! ${place2.locality!} test");

      setState(() {
        currentLocationName = place2.locality!;
      });

      return place2.locality!;
    }
  }
}
```

When i try this in normal flutter project it works fine, but it doesn't work in flutter flow[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Normal Function- use Custom Functions
For Async Function - Use Custom Actions.

But note one thing Custom Action is only triggered with some Events such as OnTap, OnPageLoad, OnChange....